# How can I modify a matrix report with a summary line?

Tags: reporting, forecast, quota

I have a matrix report I want to use to show the quota for a month and then all the activity for that month summed up and compared to the quota.  If I leave Details turned on, it will show the Quota amounts repeated for each row that has an Opportunity/Forecast Item.  Technically though, the Quota is entered by month, so I would prefer to see the quota on the summary line.  This first image is the report with Details turned on (note the Quota column with the amounts repeated on the detail lines):

[image: Report with Details turned on]

If I turn Details off, then the report is exactly what I want except that the Quota amounts disappear (see below).  Is there any way to get these quota amounts to show on the summary lines (so they remain when the Details are turned off)?

[image: Report with Details turned off]